# UIButton ImageView contentmode doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, contentmode

I just started an app for iOS in Swift, I'm doing the design programmatically (I mean I'm not using storyboard)

I have a UIButton with an image inside, I would like the image to fill the entire button. Right now it just show the image in my button, but smaller than the button, center in top of the button frame.

My code is :

```
    let buttonLocation = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonRoundedSize, height: buttonRoundedSize))
    buttonLocation.setImage(UIImage(named: "locate_button"), for: .normal)
    buttonLocation.backgroundColor = .white
    buttonLocation.layer.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
    buttonLocation.myExtension()
```

Here are the things I've tried (none of theses worked) :

```
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    self.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    self.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

If I just put the contentMode line it doesn't work either. The imageView doesn't return nil i've checked..

Thanks!

Comment: try buttonLocation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: use `buttonLocation.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "locate_button"), for: .normal)`

Comment: @BenRockey it doesn't work

Comment: Try setting the content mode of the imageView object inside the button. Ex. buttonLocation.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

Comment: @BhargavR doesn't work either :( And I've also tried the setBackgroundImage and I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentMode` of `buttonLocation's` `imageView` as `scaleAspectFill` or `scaleToFill` to cover the entire `frame` of `button`.

```
let buttonLocation = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 500))
buttonLocation.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .normal)
buttonLocation.backgroundColor = .gray
buttonLocation.layer.cornerRadius = buttonLocation.frame.width / 2
buttonLocation.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill //Here........
```

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing as you can see in my first post, and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code and remove other properties which are being set for this button :

```
let buttonLocation = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        buttonLocation.setImage(UIImage(named: "cat"), for: .normal)
        buttonLocation.backgroundColor = .white
        buttonLocation.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        buttonLocation.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        buttonLocation.clipsToBounds = true

        self.view.addSubview(buttonLocation)
```

Here make sure that the image which you are setting in the button is larger than the frame of the button. You can change frame and corner radius values in the above code. I just tried with the above code and getting below output.

[image]

You can comment if this is not your expected output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work and my image size is higher than the unbutton size so I really don't understand why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Answer on your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263623/3047318

TLDR: set contentMode in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score -1):

you need to use setBackgroundImage property instead of setImage.

```
buttonLocation.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "locate_button"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Same problem with setBackgroundImage instead of setImage

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
let buttonLocation = UIButton(type: .custom)
buttonLocation.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonRoundedSize, height: buttonRoundedSize)
buttonLocation.setImage(UIImage(named: "locate_button"), for: .normal)
buttonLocation.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
buttonLocation.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
buttonLocation.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
buttonLocation.backgroundColor = .white
buttonLocation.layer.cornerRadius = frame.width / 2
buttonLocation.clipsToBounds = true
```

You need to add `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment` properties and don't forget set `clipsToBounds` to true to see the corner raius effect.

Comment: Same problem even with all that

Comment: What do you call inside the `myExtension()`. Try to remove `imageEdgeInsets` and test again.